# How to print pattern in liquid shopify

Tags: pattern-matching, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to create pattern like this https://prnt.sc/1skp2s0
I'm trying it with liquid code

```
{% for i in (1..10) %}
{% for j in (1..10) %}
{{i}}
{% endfor %}

{% assign i=i | plus : '1' %} 
<br>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable and 
 tag like this, it will help you to print the result like this
[image]

```
{% assign j = 1 %}
{% for i in (1..10) %}
  {% for j in (1..j) %}
    {{j}}
  {% endfor %}
  {% assign j = j | plus: 1 %}
  <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Its was really helpful to me
Thanks